# Execute Date arithmetic without daylight saving adjustment

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I want to parse a Date from a String in NYC timezone, add 1 day and then output string.

like:

1. parse to date
2. add 1 day
3. output

The problem is, that when I parse a date during the adjustment for daylight saving, the day in step 1 already will have extra hour and when I add 1 day, the next day will have that extra hour which is wrong for the next day, due next Day is not the day when daylight saving adjustment happens.

example:

input date March 10 2am

parsed date: March 10 3am

add 1 day => March 11 3am // has to be March 11 2am

But if you parse directly March 11 2am, then it's correct:

input date March 11 2am

parsed date => March 11 2am

So, I need to parse a Date, add 1 day and only after that execute that smart adjustment:

input date March 10 2am

parsed date: March 10 2am //do not be smart here, still 2 am

add 1 day => March 11 **2am** // here you can be smart and adjust for daylight saving if needed

this code is incorrect and shows 7am March 11 instead of 6am

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class MainApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat in = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd-HH.mm");
            in.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
            

            Date date = in.parse("20240310-02.00");
            
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTime(date);
            calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
            date = calendar.getTime();
            
            System.out.println(in.format(date)); // prints 20240311-03.00, but has to be 20240311-02.00
            
            //parse 11 march directly, works ok
            Date date2 = in.parse("20240311-02.00");
            System.out.println(in.format(date2)); // prints 20240311-02.00
            
            
        } catch (ParseException e) {e.printStackTrace();}       
    }
}
```

Comment: To start with, never use `java.util.Date`, _especially_ not `java.util.Calendar`, or any other date/time classes in `java.util`.  There is no reason to use anything but `java.time`, which is significantly better in many respects; you have discovered yourself that these classes are not particularly good at their jobs.

Comment: @LouisWasserman, I see. I also tried to use classes LocalDateTime \ ZonedDateTime - still, no luck

Comment: You will need to show the exact code you used there for us to help.

Comment: So, I used `LocalDateTime`, added 1 day to it (`LocalDateTime.parse("20240310-02.00", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd-HH.mm")).plusDays(1);`) and then wrapped it in a `ZonedDateTime` (`ZonedDateTime.of(ldt, ZoneId.of("America/New_York"))`) without any issues, this gave me `2024-03-11T02:00-04:00[America/New_York]` - I would, however, test this assumption across a number of different default time zones to make use that `LocalDateTime` isn't making use of JVM's default time zone - but that's me

Comment: Ideally you would educate the publisher of your data about using only standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats when exchanging date-time data as text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### java.time

I recommend you avoid using the outdated and error-prone `java.util` date/time API and do it using the [modern date/time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html), `java.time`.

Your given date-time string does not have time zone information. Therefore, you should parse it to a `LocalDateTime` instance.

**Demo**:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDateTime = "20240310-02.00";
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuuMMdd-HH.mm", Locale.ENGLISH);
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(strDateTime, dtf);
        LocalDateTime nextDate = ldt.plusDays(1);
        System.out.println(ldt);
        System.out.println(nextDate);

        // In case you need to format nextDate in the input format
        System.out.println(nextDate.format(dtf));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2024-03-10T02:00
2024-03-11T02:00
20240311-02.00
```

#### [Online Demo](https://ideone.com/dCbJIz)

You can convert a `LocalDateTime` into a `ZonedDateTime` by applying a `ZoneId`.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of(nextDate, zoneId);
System.out.println(zdt);
```

**Output**:

```
2024-03-11T02:00-04:00[America/New_York]
```

Learn about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**

Comment: Thank you for this, but this solution has the opposite problem - it does not adjust for day time saving when it is actually needed, like, if we do not add the 1 day, "20240310-02.00" has to be parsed to "20240310-03.00"

Comment: I'll update my answer with some more information in a few minutes.

Comment: I've updated your code, and it looks good!

        `String strDateTime = "20240310-02.00";
          DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuuMMdd-HH.mm", Locale.ENGLISH);
          LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(strDateTime, dtf);
          LocalDateTime nextDate = ldt.plusDays(1);
          ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ldt.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
          ZonedDateTime zonedNextDayDateTime = nextDate.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
          System.out.println(zonedDateTime);
          System.out.println(zonedNextDayDateTime);`